# Unserialize function is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization

I am getting the issue to unserialize the data getting from database. Unserialize function is not working. I did not see any error or warnings. When I print database data and paste it in unserialize function then it is working. I am using the following code.

Database data is:

```
s:333:"a:24:{i:0;s:2:"46";i:1;s:2:"43";i:2;s:2:"42";i:3;s:2:"37";i:4;s:2:"36";i:5;s:2:"35";i:6;s:2:"33";i:7;s:2:"31";i:8;s:2:"30";i:9;s:2:"28";i:10;s:2:"26";i:11;s:2:"24";i:12;s:2:"22";i:13;s:2:"20";i:14;s:2:"74";i:15;s:2:"75";i:16;s:2:"77";i:17;s:2:"79";i:18;s:2:"81";i:19;s:2:"83";i:20;s:2:"85";i:21;s:2:"87";i:22;s:2:"89";i:23;s:2:"91";}";a:24:{i:0;s:2:"46";i:1;s:2:"43";i:2;s:2:"42";i:3;s:2:"37";i:4;s:2:"36";i:5;s:2:"35";i:6;s:2:"33";i:7;s:2:"31";i:8;s:2:"30";i:9;s:2:"28";i:10;s:2:"26";i:11;s:2:"24";i:12;s:2:"22";i:13;s:2:"20";i:14;s:2:"74";i:15;s:2:"75";i:16;s:2:"77";i:17;s:2:"79";i:18;s:2:"81";i:19;s:2:"83";i:20;s:2:"85";i:21;s:2:"87";i:22;s:2:"89";i:23;s:2:"91";}
```

The code i'm using is:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` LIKE 'Assign_Lead' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%".$lead_id."%'";
$scID = $wpdb->get_results($sql_query);
foreach($scID as $kc => $vc){
     print_r($vc->meta_value);
    $resutlt = unserialize($vc->meta_value);
    //print_r($resutlt);
    if(in_array($lead_id,$resutlt)){
        $scid = $vc->user_id;
        $user_info = get_userdata($scid);
        $scname = $user_info->display_name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about printing `$vc->meta_value` if value is correct ?

Comment: getting the serialize data from the database. It is database field name

Comment: First of all `unserialize` works fine, when the data is correctly serialized... So, the problem is not with `unserialize` but with your `data`...
What is `print_r` result?

Comment: It is serialize data that I have added in question

Comment: Can you do th following code and post result, thnx.

`foreach($scID as $kc=>$vc) {
print_r($vc->meta_value);
$resutlt=unserialize($vc->meta_value); 
print_r($resutlt);
}`

Comment: I have post the result in question. you can check both outputs.

Comment: Your data is serialized twice.

Comment: it is showing the same result after unserialize

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify i=x when you are using a simple array.
Doing this can help you

```
a:24:{s:2:"46";s:2:"43";s:2:"42";s:2:"37"..}
```

If you use an array in the array then you need to specify i=x in that.

Comment: `i=x`? What is it?

Comment: LIke you are doing i:0;s:2:"47" so do it s:2:"47"

Comment: I am saving the serialize data in database,  For new value, getting the value from database, unserialize it then add the new value in existing then serialize it  again and update it in database